# Mendix and Azure Ad B2C AuthRequest does not have assertion consumer service URL

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml, mendix

I try to get Azure AD B2C working on Mendix.
We have it working with the normal Azure AD this is quite easy because all is done in a gui.
For Azure AD B2C this is done in XML so a bit harder.

I have followed the next tutorials and this works all.
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers

If I try now to get it working with mendix I get the next error:
Application registered corresponding to IssuerUri "https://xxxx.mendixcloud.com" in AuthRequest does not have assertion consumer service URL "https://xxx.mendixcloud.com/SSO/assertion" specified in its metadata.

In the SAMLApp1 Manifest, I put the Mendix Metadata URL. That is the only thing that I need to change so far I can find.

Can someone maybe help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SAMLApp1 Manifest you must change the identifierURI to https://xxxx.mendixcloud.com (issuer in the SAML request from mendix).

The metadata at 'https://xxx.mendixcloud.com/SSO/assertion' must have an ACS URL within it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I missed that setting.