# Azure B2C SAML Authentication - AuthRequest does not have assertion consumer service URL error

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I've followed the steps from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy

While testing receiving the error "Application registered corresponding to IssuerUri "">xyz.com/suite" in AuthRequest does not have assertion consumer service URL "">xyz.com/suite/saml/AssertionConsumer" specified in its metadata.</samlp:StatusMessage>"

Using SAML tracer, I can see both my SAML Request and Response contains same AssertionConsumerServiceURL.
MS document says: If you choose to configure the reply URL and logout URL in the application manifest without populating the application's metadata endpoint via the samlMetadataUrl property, Azure AD B2C will not validate the SAML request signature, nor will it encrypt the SAML response.

I can some workaround of specifying the PartnerEntity in the SP metadata URL for the Relying Party in the B2C_1A_signup_signin_saml custom policy.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/61603

Unfortunately my web application security compliance does not allow to provide SP metadata endpoints.
Do I need to host the SP / Appian SAML metadata file on Azure Storage account OR Is this mandatory to provide SP meta data endpoint to refer from  Idp application registration manifest?

Second question, just want to make sure on the below.
From MS Ref. doc: You can change the value of the IssuerUri metadata item in the SAML token issuer technical profile. This change will be reflected in the issuerUri attribute returned in the SAML response from Azure AD B2C. Your application should be configured to accept the same issuerUri during SAML response validation.

My question on the above paragraph,
IssueUri example can be .onmicrosoft.com/c3bcfc1c-1234-4a3b-96e6-db0933071234 (application / client id) Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: This issue has been resolved, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65710654/mendix-and-azure-ad-b2c-authrequest-does-not-have-assertion-consumer-service-url
However, now displaying an error "The username or password provided in the request are invalid". Though my b2c username and password are correct not sure why I get this error...In B2B, I used to assign the user access to registered app whereas in B2C I don't see any such option, I was wondering how system will recognize B2C local account user has access privilege to the application?

Comment: Is this when you start from the SAML SP? Are you sure you are getting to the correct tenant? Try setting up a simple user flow for sign in and then "Run user flow" using those credentials. If that works, you have a SAML problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The username or password provided in the request are invalid" - This issue has been resolved by granting "IdentityExperienceFramework" (User_impersonation - Delegated Type) API permission. I could not see this solution on MS documents guidance, however this has resolved my issue. thanks.